Possibility of making a custom filter excluding duplicates and closed questions in the question view
This is very similar to Is there a way exclude duplicates and closed questions in the question view?
The accepted answer indicates that you can add you can add closed:no duplicate:no migrated:no in the search bar, but it seems that you can't add it to a custom filter.

Currently, I don't think there is a way to add those exclusions.

You're asking if it's possible but you've tagged this as a feature request. These two are at odds. The answer to "is it possible" is "no" with a tagged on "you can create a feature request to it". The answer to a feature request is potential feedback on the request and/or eventually implementing it.

If I don't know if there is a way to do it, I have to ask if it is possible, but because I don't think it is, I would like it to be a feature.

I had an answer outlining what custom filters do and don't do. However, that would have been an answer to a [[tag;support]] question and completely unfit for a [[tag:feature-request]]. So, I discarded the answer and posted a comment instead.

I edited my question to be feature-request oriented.
